# Convert ASCII string array into its hex value array

Tags: c, hex, ascii, data-representation

I have a `char` array which contains ASCII characters. I need to know how to get the hex value of each character and save it in a `uint8_t` array.

E.g. if I have

```
array[5] = "ABCDE"
```

The output should be

```
output[5] = {0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45}
```

I tried using [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) but didn't work.

```
for(unsigned i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    message[i] = (uint8_t)strtol(&incoming_message[i], NULL, 16);
}

Output:
A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 F 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

**Update:** This is for a program I'm writing for a [*Cortex-M0+ processor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M#Cortex-M0+). I'm not just viewing incoming data, I'm processing this data in the next step. Therefore, no use of `printf`

Comment: `uint8_t` can't contain hex values; and `"ABCDE"` is equivalent to `{0x41,0x42,0x43,0x44,0x45,0}`. Just cast. (Also as a sidenote, `"ABCDE"` doesn't fit into `array[5]`, as it has 6 elements, because strings are NUL-terminated, as shown in the equivalent byte array.

Comment: Yes. That's just an example. But thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: `"ABCDE"` is an array of **6** `char`s as there is added a 0 terminator. I'm not sure whether the compiler complains or implicitly fixes `char array[5] = "ABCDE";`. However, you may access the first 5 `char`s. The expected output are already the corresponding ASCII values (as already pointed out) and `sizeof (char) == sizeof (uint8_t)`. So, this can be reduced to a simple copy: `memcpy(output, array, 5);`. (But, if you can't use `memcpy()` for any reasons a simple `for` loop should do as well.)

Comment: Regarding `char array[5] = "ABCDE";` - I checked this out: The compilers (gcc HEAD 9.0.0, clang HEAD 7.0.0, both with `-pedantic`) don't complain but fixes this implicitly: [Test on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WOJmW7rZbCQ1QQhQ). (Early in the morning but already learned something...) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff: `array[5] = "ABCDE"` is special. It defines (and initialises) a `char`-array with ***five*** elements (only). No `0`-terminator here. This is in line with the C11 standard.

Comment: @Amadan I overlooked that you mentioned `char array[5]` vs. `"ABCDE"` already before. So, my other comment might be interesting as well as the note of alk concerning this.

Comment: Thanks alk. Still - you don't need even a memcpy, just a cast. `incoming_message` _is_ `message`.

Comment: You do not even need to cast. Please see my answer.

Comment: "Therefore, no use of printf" and "The output should be ..." --> What output function is acceptable as you dis-allow `printf()`?

Comment: @chux Let me explain. I'm developing a software for a STM32L0 series microcontroller which contains a CortexM0+ processor. It does not contain a ITM trace so no use of printf as I cannot view the data. I'm constructing a message using sprintf and sending it to hardware encryption block for encryption. I found out that I need to input this data as hex values. I'm transmitting this using a LoRa radio and sniffing the incoming data packets using a receiver.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) like all other string functions expects a ***null-terminated*** byte string, not single characters.

Secondly, the characters encoded value is the actual value of the elements in your string. If you print the decimal value `65` (for example) using the correct format specifier, then the character `A` will be printed:

```
printf("%c\n", 65);  // Will print an A
```

Similarly, printing the character `'A'` as a decimal integer will print the value `65`:

```
printf("%d\n", 'A');  // Will print the value 65
```

So all you need to do is to print the values in your array in the correct format.

---

***Furthermore...*** All values on computers the last few decades are stored in *binary*. All of them.

Decimal, octal or hexadecimal are just how you present the values. Storing `0x41`, `61`, `0101` or `0b01000001` (for compilers with binary notation extension) doesn't matter since in the end it will be the binary value that is stored. If you want to show a value as hexadecimal to a user through some output, you have to format the binary value as such when printing or writing it.

Comment: I think the `OP`wants also to save the `hex`values in an `uint8_t` array as he mentioned.

Comment: @Alan Which is really impossible (added note about it).

Comment: programmer Saw it, didn't think about it! Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry forgot to mention, this is for an embedded system. printf is not available for me.

Comment: @ADGAN Then you probably use some other method of presenting the values? Because no matter what it's just a presentational issue.

Answer (score 4):

1. Talking C a `char` is the smallest integer value available.
2. Talking C and ASCII a character literal (like `'A'`) is just another representation of an **`int`** value (`65` here).
3. Talking Math there are other ways to *represent* the very same value, aside the decimal way (using base 10). One common is using the base of 16, the hexadecimal way.

Putting the above together it proves that:

```
int i = 'A';
char c = i;
```

is the same as:

```
int i = 65; 
char c = i;
```

and the same as:

```
int i = 0x41; 
char c = i;
```

and the same as:

```
char c = 'A';
```

and the same as:

```
char c = 65;
```

and the same as:

```
char c = 0x41;
```

So

```
char a[5] = "ABCDE";
```

in fact already is an integer array of five (small) integers.

If printed using the correct *conversion specifier* and *length modifier* you see what you are after.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
  printf("%hhx ", a[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
41 42 43 44 45
```

To indicate to the reader this should be taken as hexadecimal values one could prefix the value using the common `0x` notation

```
  printf("0x%hhx ", a[i]);
```

which gave you

```
0x41 0x42 0x43 0x44 0x45
```

If you would show this to Pascal guys you perhaps would use

```
  printf("$%hhx ", a[i]);
```

which gave you

```
$41 $42 $43 $44 $45
```

To see the characters themselves just us:

```
  printf("%c ", a[i]);
```

and get

```
A B C D E
```

To see the decimal values use

```
  printf("%d ", a[i]);
```

and get

```
65 66 67 68 69
```

The conclusion is, that it's all just matter of how you represent ("print") the ***same values*** (the content of `a`'s elements) . The "conversion" happens when creating the *representation* of a very same value (via printing and passing the right "instructions"), that is during output only.

---

As you refer to ASCII only, this implies all value are <128, so you can just plain copy the array's values using either a loop

```
char src[5] = "ABCDE";
uint8_t dst[5];

for (size_t i = 0 i < 5; ++i)
{
  dst[i] = src[i];
}
```

or by copying the related memory block at once

```
memcpy(dst, src, 5);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can convert the value to hexadecimal using the basic algorithm i.e division by 16.
I have created the following function where you can pass the string to be converted and a an array of strings where you will get the response.

```
void hexCon(char str[],char result[][5]){
    int i,check,rem = 0;
    char res[20],res2[20];        
    int len = 0;    
    char temp;          

    for(i=0; i < strlen(str) ; i++){
        len=0;
        check = str[i];
        while(check > 0){
        rem = check%16;
        switch(rem){
            case 10:temp='A';break;
            case 11:temp='B';break;
            case 12:temp='C';break;
            case 13:temp='D';break;
            case 14:temp='E';break;
            case 15:temp='F';break;
            default:temp=rem + '0';
        }
        res[len] = temp;       
        check = check /16;
        len++;    
    }

    reverse(res,len,res2);  //reversing the digits
    res2[len] = '\0';       //adding null character at the end of string
    strcpy(result[i],res2); //copying all data to result array
    }
}
```

where reverse function is :

```
void reverse(char str[], int size, char rev[]) 
{       
    int i=0,j=0;
    for(i=size-1 , j=0 ; i >= 0; i-- , j++ ){
        rev[j] = str[i];
    }    
}
```

you can call it like :

```
void main(){    
    char str[]="ABCDE";
    char result[strlen(str)][5];
    int i;
    hexCon(str,result);
    for(i =0 ;i < strlen(str); i++){
        printf("%s\n",result[i]);
    }
}
```

the algorithm used is explained here :-
https://www.permadi.com/tutorial/numDecToHex/

Hope this helps :)

Comment: How does this answer the question in its whole?